# error CS1759 while building VSIX project in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I created a new VSIX project, added a new custom command item, tried to build, and I got those 2 errors:

> error CS1759: Cannot embed interop types from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it is
>   missing either the
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute'
>   attribute or the
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute'
>   attribute.
>
> error CS1759: Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it is missing either the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute.

what could be the problem?

If it helps, I followed this Microsoft guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138589.aspx

thanks!

- **EDIT:**
  I changed in the properties of the references "...shell.interop" and "...OLE.interop" the field "Embed Interop Types" from True to False and it works. do someone know why?
  Thanks.

Comment: Same experience: True -> False and it works without error

Answer (score 2):

As the author mentions, change the Embed Interop Types property to false for both of these assembly.